# MySQL join two tables with group by in each

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql tables with part numbers and qty's. I want to sum each tables qty `sum(qty) ... group by partNumber` Then join the two tables on the part number.

Sometimes table A will have part numbers that table b does not and vice versa. Below is an image of what I am expecting.

I've tried something like this, but this returns a row for each table and I want it to return 1 combined row

```
SELECT *, null as macroQty, sum(qty) as cardinalQty 
  FROM parts.cardinal where fileinfoid IN 
   (select cardinalFiles from parts.reports where fileinfoid = 418) 
GROUP BY partNumber UNION ALL
SELECT *, sum(qty) as macroQty, null as cardinalQty 
  FROM parts.macro where fileinfoid IN 
    (select macroFiles from parts.reports where fileinfoid = 418 ) 
GROUP BY partNumber
```

I also tried wrapping it in an outer select and grouping by the part number from the outer select like this, but this results in the second inner select being null always

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, null as macroQty, sum(qty) as cardinalQty 
    FROM parts.cardinal where fileinfoid IN 
     (select cardinalFiles from parts.reports where fileinfoid = 418) 
  GROUP BY partNumber UNION ALL
  SELECT *, sum(qty) as macroQty, null as cardinalQty 
    FROM parts.macro where fileinfoid IN 
      (select macroFiles from parts.reports where fileinfoid = 418 ) 
  GROUP BY partNumber
) combined GROUP BY combined.partNumber
```

[image]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Why don't you want part number "1111" in the table b col in your result? I see 111 qty is 5, are there any other conditions?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that in the image. The result table should have 5 for qty-b for part number 111

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to identify unique part numbers across the 2 tables (using a UNION with it's applied distinct) and then use correlated sub queries to get the sums. For example

```
drop table if exists a,b;

create table a(id int,val int);
create table b(id int,val int);

insert into a values(1,10),(1,10),(3,10),(4,10);
insert into b values (2,10),(4,10),(4,10);

select (select sum(a.val) from a where a.id = s.id) aval,
         (select sum(b.val) from b where b.id = s.id) bval,
         s.id partno
from
(
select id from a
union select id from b
) s
order by s.id;

+------+------+--------+
| aval | bval | partno |
+------+------+--------+
|   20 | NULL |      1 |
| NULL |   10 |      2 |
|   10 | NULL |      3 |
|   10 |   20 |      4 |
+------+------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase this as a join between two subqueries which each find the sum in their respective tables.  However, since each table does not necessarily contain all part numbers, and in fact there may be part numbers unique to each table, we will have to use a full outer join approach.

```
SELECT
    t1.partNumber,
    t1.cardinalQty,
    COALECSE(t2.macroQty, 0) AS macroQty
FROM
(
    SELECT partNumber, SUM(qty) AS cardinalQty
    FROM cardinal
    GROUP BY partNumber
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT partNumber, SUM(qty) AS macroQty
    FROM macro
    GROUP BY partNumber
) t2
    ON t1.partNumber = t2.partNumber

UNION ALL

SELECT
    t2.partNumber,
    0 AS cardinalQty,
    t2.macroQty
FROM
(
    SELECT partNumber, SUM(qty) AS cardinalQty
    FROM cardinal
    GROUP BY partNumber
) t1
RIGHT JOIN
(
    SELECT partNumber, SUM(qty) AS macroQty
    FROM macro
    GROUP BY partNumber
) t2
    ON t1.partNumber = t2.partNumber
WHERE t1.partNumber IS NULL;
```

Keep in mind that under normal conditions, in a well designed database, you should rarely encounter a situation which requires using a full outer join.  Actually, a full outer join screams out that there is a design problem.  In this case, you don't have a single parts table containing all part numbers.  That table should exist, so unless you enjoy big ugly queries, you should create a parts table where the `partNumber` is a primary key.

Comment: Table A will always have part numbers that Table B does not --

Table B will always have part numbers that Table A does not

Comment: @BrianMcCall I gave you an option which should work, but keep in mind you currently have really bad table design.  Unless you want to put big, ugly, queries as you see above into production, fix your design problem.

Comment: I wish. Basically the problem is I have to compare two spread sheets to find the differences. The spreadsheets come from two different companies at different times. I am playing with your example now and altering it. I provided a dumbed down example for this SO question. @TimBiegeleisen